# How to show startup progress in a web application?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web, startup

I'm sure almost everyone has worked on a project where the web application took more than 5 minutes to boot.  This means from a cold start, you could send a request from your browser and sit patiently watching a blank screen.  A few months back I installed a suite of Atlassian products (JIRA, Stash, Confluence).  These are large applications as well and can take a while to boot up; however, I loved what I saw in one of them.  The request returned almost immediately and instead of a blank screen, it provided a progress bar and showed what modules were currently being loaded.  I love this idea but am unsure of how they accomplished it.

Specifically, has anyone seen this in an Atlassian product?  And if so, do you know how they accomplished it?

Comment: I narrowed the question to specifically how does the Atlassian products do this 2 days ago when the first votes came in.  Is that not specific enough?

Answer (score 2):

Webservers are actually quite fast to start. Sound's like they first fire up the webserver with a static page using javascript to connect into the main server and update the status. Or perhaps they publish the status back to this static page during startup and just uses javascript to reload the page within an interval.

I've seen both used in the wild.